# ORM market analysis

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

I would like to see your experience with popular ORM tools outhere, like NHibernate, LLBLGen, EF, S2Q, Genom-e, LightSpeed, DataObjects.NET, OpenAccess, ...

From my exp:
 - Genom-e is quiet capable of Linq & performance, dev support
 - EF lacks on some key features like lazy loading, Poco support, pers.ignorance... but in 4.o it may  have overcome ..
 - DataObjects.Net so far good, althrough I found some bugs
 - NHibernate steep learning curve, no 100% Linq support (like in Genom-e and DataObjects.Net), but very supportive, extensible and mature

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @bonefisher. Poll type questions should be asked with the "community wiki" checkbox checked. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.ormbattle.net/

THat is about the best comparison you can find at the moment.

From my experience, btw.: Stay AWAY from NHibernate current release if you have interest in LINQ - use the development branch. The LINQ support mvoes into the main DLL AND - more important - is a lot better and complete than the limited add on methods in the current releases.

Comment: ormbattle.net is not really a good way to evaluate differenct Orm tools as the that benchmarking is kind of useless in production code.

Comment: depends. At least it ALSO gives you features. For example you can see whether implementations of for example LINQ features are good or bad. Many of the benchmarks are feature tests.

Comment: On orm battle the best tool is project, where you need to write all required SQL in attributes for objects. Do you think its a good ORM?

Comment: @Sli: depends on what you want do.. the DO.Net is DDD driven or 'code first' driven, so using it for some Legacy DB is maybe not suitable..

Answer (score 4):

- [ORM Meter](http://www.ormeter.net/)
- [Should I ever use Entity Framework 4.0?](https://www.withoutbugs.com/2011/04/should-i-ever-use-entity-framework-40.html)
- [NHibernate – The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly, that it gets!](https://www.withoutbugs.com/2011/04/nhibernate-good-bad-and-ugly-that-it.html)

[image]
<sub>(source: [ormeter.net](http://ormeter.net/images/stories/results-2009.10/Scorecard-LINQ.png))</sub>

Comment: thank you for the chart but I already saw this site weeks ago.. I wanted to know personal experience not some diagnostics on synthetic benchmarks

Comment: That won't work. Seriously - personal experience is very personal on personal project demands. Some people work perfectly with LINQ, but most of the time if you ask behind it is because they dont have a clue what a ORM is capable of acutally, and are totally happy to ahve something better than crappy handwritten stuff.

Comment: you still can have a good experience with an ORM (bug-free, good functionality, support) and a bad experience (too many bugs, crappy functionality, delayed (or even none!) support from company/community.. so IMHO I think this is a valid question.

Comment: Just one point: I'm using EF4.0 in an enterprise level sales MIS and tell you that it is totally not for this scale of applications. Poor performance and huge query size with large TPT hierarchies, long waits while updating the model, not being able to use entities as parameters in queries, lack of control over batch lazy loading, lack of caching facilities, crazy loading of large collections just for association fixup, no bulk insert/updates are just some of the problems. Well I should say that we managed to get around all of them, but it's definitely not a charm.

Answer (score 2):

We made a really in-deep analysis two years ago (2010) betweeen NHibernate, EF and Llblgen and chose the last one. We definitely think we made the right decision.

Llblgen Pro is a gorgeous & mature ORM (Entity FW needs to evolve yet: direct m:n, enum, inheritance...). Easy to use both model and database first without XML to see, just a good graphical designer.

- Highly efficient: get only the columns you need ... or use TypedList to get commonly used joined/grouped columns ... or map your views with TypedViews, or map your retrieve Store Procedures ...or use ad-hoc queries. You could even create some templates mapping your own POCO (TypeValue) and call SQL directly!!! (we haven't needed to go so far)
- From the designer, use its own framework, or NHibernate or Entity Framework, or LINQ to SQL
- Quite a lot of functionality you'd miss once you've decided to go into production (prefetch, transactions, databinding helpers, paging, (de)serialization, customization (properties, dependency injection, authorization, auditing, ...)

...but it is much more: a great model designer & template system.

From the ORM on:

- A good use of custom templates (ex. ASP.Net, MVC, REST or WCF) provides a
  scaffolding system/common architecture -> allows the less experienced coders to catchup
  and be more productive. Common solutions are reused (its cost drops
  down: it's not "code vs. understand & integrate" but "code vs.
  plug"). Although it's old-fashioned ASP.Net webforms have a look at
  http://northwind.angte-demo.com/ for a feeling of what you can get
  with the templates.
- Code for your particular application in VS as usual. If the code is
  reusable add the code to the template (it usually means changing in a ASP-like file
  things like "Product" with "<%=Entity.Name%>", not hard staff).